# Usb stick does not mount automatically

Tags: usb, mount

Currently, I can not use any usb stick or external hard disk in Ubuntu 12.04 via graphics user interface. While trying to mount them manually, I realized that they are actually mounted automatically at /media/usb0,usb1 etc. However, I can't use the file manager to do something on the usb. I want to use file manager to copy, cut etc. In addition, while the usb is being mounted automatically, it's symbol does not appear on the left menu (dash home) which prevents me to safely remove the usb easily.
How will be really thankful if somebody help me on this please?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
dmesg
```

to find what name your device has, something like /dev/sdb1 or so.

Then mount it with (media/usb0 exists):

```
mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /media/usb0 && ls /media/usb0
```

Comment: Dear David,I have updated the original post, and will be glad if you look at it again.